# NodeJS with Sequelize and Typescript

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I would like to be able to create models from my code to mysql database.
The problem is that the tables are not being created..
I don't any good documentation to use sequelize with typescript..

index.ts

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from "cors";
import helmet from "helmet";
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
import { sequelize } from "./config/sequelize";
import routes from "./routes";

dotenv.config();

    // Create a new express application instance
    const app = express();
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(helmet());
    app.use(express.json());

    sequelize
        .sync({ force: true })
        .then(() => {
            console.log("Connection has been established successfully.");
            app.use("/api", routes);
            app.listen(3000, () => {
                console.log('Listening...') // OK
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error("Unable to connect to the database:", err);
        });
```

sequelize.ts

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize-typescript';

export const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  database: 'node',
  dialect: 'mysql',
  username: 'root',
  password: '',
  host: 'localhost',
  models: ['../entities']
})
```

entities/users.ts

```
import { Table, Column, Model } from 'sequelize-typescript';

@Table
class Users extends Model {
  @Column
    name!: string;

  @Column
    age!: number;

  @Column
    breed!: string;
}
```

So my users table is not being created.. I don't understand why, the connection to the db is OK.
Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sequelize doesn't create the tables for you. The model is "only" a tool for performing CRUD operations on the User entities.

You need to create the table structures manually, or better use a migration tool such as [mysql-migrations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-migrations).

Comment: Hum ok :(  
I was thinking the @Table was for that..

Answer (score 0):

you will have to initialize the model by calling
`sequelize.addModels([Users])`

then create the table by calling
`await User.sync()`

Comment: When you answer a question, please explain why